# Inserir registro no banco dentro de um for usando hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Preciso de ajuda, estou tentando criar um lançamento de despesa fixa. tenho que inserir por exemplo 12 registros no banco de dados, através de um loop dentro do for.

Para inserir os dados estou usando o hibernate, porem ele só insere uma linha, as 11 linhas que ele deveria inserir ele nao insere, ja debuguei e nao ha erros

```
for (int i = 1; i <= duracaoRepeticao; i++) {
                System.out.println("loop : " + i);
                Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); // cria gregorian calendar
                calendar.setTime(dataLancamento); // seta a data informada no formulario no calendar

                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, i); // seta incrementalmente (mensalmente) o mes, mantendo a data statica
                Date dataLancamentoIncremental = calendar.getTime();                   lancamentoDados.setDataLancamentoDados(dataLancamentoIncremental);
                lancamentoDados.setCategoria(lancamentoDados.getCategoria());
                lancamentoDados.setValorPagoLancamentoDados(123);
                lancamentoDadosDao.adiciona(lancamentoDados); // cadastra detalhes do lancamento, parcela, despesa fixa...
            }
```

### Esse é a saida no log do tomcat

```
Um por mes
loop : 1
data: Sat Jul 02 00:00:00 BRT 2016
Passei perto
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        LANCAMENTO_DADO
        (LCD_COD_CAT_COD, LCD_COD_CTA_COD, LCD_DATAPARALANCAR, LCD_COD_PES_COD, LCD_COD_LCA_COD, LCD_STATUS, LCD_COD_SCT_COD, LCD_VALOR, LCD_VALORPAGO) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Passe do session
loop : 2
data: Tue Aug 02 00:00:00 BRT 2016
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 3
data: Fri Sep 02 00:00:00 BRT 2016
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 4
data: Sun Oct 02 00:00:00 BRT 2016
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 5
data: Wed Nov 02 00:00:00 BRST 2016
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 6
data: Fri Dec 02 00:00:00 BRST 2016
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 7
data: Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 BRST 2017
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 8
data: Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 BRST 2017
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 9
data: Thu Mar 02 00:00:00 BRT 2017
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 10
data: Sun Apr 02 00:00:00 BRT 2017
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 11
data: Tue May 02 00:00:00 BRT 2017
Passei perto
Passe do session
loop : 12
data: Fri Jun 02 00:00:00 BRT 2017
Passei perto
Passe do session
```

Alguem sabe me ajuda ?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente a unica coisa que pode esta dando esse problema ai e essa sua variável `duracaoRepeticao` ela realmente esta com valor 12 ?
printa ela no log pra poder ver...

Comment: Esta sim, verifiquei aqui.  o visualizador do tomcat apartir do loop dois nao se ve ação de insert como esta acima

Comment: Pelo que da pra ver, em todo o loop lançamento dados é um unico objeto
voce deveria criar um novo objeto a cada loop

`for(int i=0;i<duracaoRepeticao;i++){
     LancamentoDados lancamentosDados = new LancamentoDados();
    //preenche o objeto
   lancamentosDadosDao.adiciona(lancamentosDados);

}`

Comment: Deu certo aqui, valew, problema resolvido

Comment: Posta sua solução ai, E se a resposta foi util nao esquece de marca-la. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Segue a solução para inserir dados no banco pelo hibernate em um for

```
 for (int i = 0; i < duracaoRepeticao; i++) {  
                    // é necessario criar um novo objeto da classe LancamentoDados para ele inserir os registros, se nao ele soh insere o primeira linha
                    LancamentoDados dados = new LancamentoDados();
                    dados.setLancamento(lancamentoDados.getLancamento());
                    dados.setValorLancamentoDados(lancamentoDados.getValorLancamentoDados());
                    dados.setValorPagoLancamentoDados(lancamentoDados.getValorPagoLancamentoDados());
                    dados.setDataLancamentoDados(lancamentoDados.getDataLancamentoDados());
                    dados.setCategoria(lancamentoDados.getCategoria());
                    dados.setSubCategoria(lancamentoDados.getSubCategoria());
                    dados.setFornecedor(lancamentoDados.getFornecedor());
                    dados.setConta(lancamentoDados.getConta());
                    // ---------------------------------------------------------     
                    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); // cria gregorian calendar
                    calendar.setTime(dataLancamento); // seta a data informada no formulario no calendar                    
                    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, i); // seta incrementalmente (mensalmente) o mes, mantendo a data statica

                    Date dataLancamentoIncremental = calendar.getTime();
                    dados.setDataLancamentoDados(dataLancamentoIncremental);
                    System.out.println(df.format(dataLancamentoIncremental));
                    lancamentoDadosDao.adiciona(dados); // cadastra detalhes do lancamento, parcela, despesa fixa...


                }
```